# Remote Starter/Bypass Module Issue - 1999 Buick Regal [Viper 4103XV and XpressKit PLJX Bypass]

Tags: starting, starter, security, buick

I have a 1999 Buick Regal that I installed a Viper 4103XV remote starter [3/4 installed, anyway :)] and XpressKit PLJX bypass module in.

I've yet to be able to get it to start consistently is the #1 issue that I've got. Usually after programming the bypass module it'll remote start a few times, and then it just decides it doesn't want to any more. **The remote starter will try to start the car, but when voltage is applied to the starter circuit, nothing happens - this is why I suspect the bypass module as the culprit.**

**---Lately even after programming the bypass it won't start. Still will if I just insert the key either before [still don't have to turn the key at all], or while it's attempting to start, but if it's not in there then nothing happens.**

I'm quite stumped at this point. The bypass says after programming to connect the brown ground wire to the "ground output on the remote starter" although the 4103XV's wiring guide isn't at all clear about what wire that is. I'd think it's either the status wire on the satellite harness, or the orange "ground when locked" wire in the main harness, but I just don't know.

Because it'll start with the key in and not turned I'd think it may be the keysense wire, but I tried hooking that up [perhaps incorrectly] and it didn't seem to make a difference.

I'm quite desperate for help as I'd really prefer to not have to take it to a shop to get it done since I've got the vast majority of it done successfully myself.

Thanks in advance!

-Sootah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**: As is turns out, I was not connected to the VATS resistor value/ground reference wires at all. The PLJX instructions SUCK and give almost no info on VATS systems while everything is written up more for the older Passlock I and II systems. I had followed the instructions as spot-on as I could and found the yellow/black/green wire that was inside a grey sheath in the ignition harness and hooked up in to that. According to the PLJX instructions yellow was resistance ref, black ground, and green was keysense, although that one likely wasn't required to be hooked up.

As it turns out for VATS the actual VATS value wires are in a different grey sheath [orange in some vehicles] and is traceable all the way back to the key cylinder itself. Inside this sheath are two TINY white [or yellow] wires. You then have to SUPER carefully strip them with a razor as even the smallest gauge hole in my wire strippers didn't even nick the insulation. Then read each with a multi-meter. With the key in the ignition and in the ON position the resistance reference wire will read a few volts. The ground will most likely read almost nothing or negative voltage.

Also - the "ground output from remote starter" is the STATUS wire on most remote starters. On my Viper 4103XV it is the blue status output wire on the satellite harness.

Once I got hooked in to the correct wires, programmed, then hooked up the PLJX to the status wire [which must be done AFTER programming] it has worked perfectly without fail since.

Figured I'd post the solution here as I finally got some help from the wonderful people at the12volt.com's forums after trying many, many other places with nobody knowing what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling omega tech on their version  (the ib-pljx) at 800 554 4053

Comment: It is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Perhaps, but if it works then I'm happy. I'll give it a try in a bit. I work nights, so it may have to wait a few days unfortunately.